# The Relation between the Slopes of Two Mutually Perpendicular Straight Lines

Tags: coordinate-systems

In coordinate geometry, we know that the product of the slopes of two mutually perpendicular straight lines is generally equal to -1. But if we consider the slopes of these two lines *y = k* (parallel to the *X*-axis) and *x = k'* (parallel to the *Y*-axis), this relation does no longer hold.  What is wrong? I have not found any satisfactory explanation. Can you help?

Comment: The vertical line has no slope within the definition (difference in y's over difference in x's) so the formula does not apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines $a_1x+b_1y=c_1$ and $a_2x+b_2y=c_2$ have slopes 
$m_1=-\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}$ and $m_2=-\dfrac{a_2}{b_2}$ respectively. As you have noticed, we have a problem when either $b_1=0$ or $b_2=0$.

Note that, when $b_1 \ne 0$ and $b_2 \ne 0$, then

\begin{align}
   m_1 \cdot m_2 = -1 
   &\implies -\dfrac{a_1}{b_1} \cdot -\dfrac{a_2}{b_2} = -1 \\
   &\implies \dfrac{a_1 \cdot a_2}{b_1 \cdot b_2} = -1 \\
   &\implies a_1 \cdot a_2 = -b_1 \cdot b_2 \\
   &\implies a_1 \cdot a_2 + b_1 \cdot b_2 = 0
\end{align}

The nice thing about the equation
$$a_1 \cdot a_2 + b_1 \cdot b_2 = 0$$

is that is also works when $a_1$ or $b_1$ or $a_2$ or $b_2$ is equal to $0$.

There is a geometrical interpretation of this.

Consider the line 
$ax+by=c$ which passes through ther point $(x_0, y_0)$. It can be shown that all points $(x,y)$ on that line sasify the vector equation 
$(x,y) = (x_0,y_0)+t(a,-b)$ where $t \in \mathbb R$ and the vector $\overrightarrow v = (a,-b)$ indicates the $``$direction$"$ of the line $ax+by=c$. It is known that two vectors are perpendicular if their dot product is $0$. Hence the two lines $a_1x+b_1y=c_1$ and $a_2x+b_2y=c_2$ are perpendicular if and only if 
$0 = (a_1,-b_1)\circ (a_2,-b_2) = a_1 \cdot a_2 + b_1 \cdot b_2$

There is a practical application of this property. The line perpendicular to the line $ax+by=c$ must be of the form $bx-ay=d$ for some number $d$ since 
$a\cdot b + b \cdot (-a) = 0$.

For example, the equation of the line passing through the point $(1,2)$ and perpendicular to the line $3x+4y=5$ is $4x-3y=4(1)-3(2)=-2$.